# C# Nullable List

Tags: c#, nullable

Are all the following valid ?  They are properties of a class instantiated to _s.

```
    public List<int>? _Int1 { get; set; }
    public List<int?> _Int2 { get; set; }
    public List<Nullable<int>> _Int3 { get; set; }
```

I've tried all of them and it all work.  However, when I assign the value, it has to match the exact way it was defined, ie:

```
        _s._Int1 = new List<int> { 0 } ;
        _s._Int2 = new List<int?> { 0 };
        _s._Int3 = new List<Nullable<int>> { 0 };
```

If I were to assign differently, then I get the following:

```
        _s._Int1 = new List<int?> { 0 } ;                   // fail
        _s._Int2 = new List<Nullable<int>> { 0 };           // OK
        _s._Int3 = new List<int?> { 0 };                    // OK
```

My questions is what is the correct way to declare a Nullable.  Thanks.

Comment: _int2 and _Int3 are identical and describe a list whose items may be null or an integer. _Int1 is a variable which may be null or  reference a list of integers.

Comment: #2 and #3 are identical...? is just a shorthand for Nullable<T>. #1 tells you that the collection itself is nullable.

Comment: #1 seems syntax error, `?` is not required there, its not nullable int

Comment: `public List<int> _Int1 = null;`  =>you can give null value to the list

Comment: For `_Int1` the list can be null but any items in that list cannot be null,  For `_Int2`, the list cannot be null but items in the list can be null.

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs.  I'm getting it now.  1 is that the list is Nullable.  2 & 3 is that it's a list but the list can contain Nullable... but then what's the different between 2/3 and a list without any items inside ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, note that `T?` can mean *two different things*:

1. If `T` is `struct`, then `T?` is `Nullable<T>`
2. If `T` is `class` then `T?` means *nullable reference type*, it means that the instance is *not supposed to be null*

PLease, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references for details

In your question `int?` is a **case #1**, since `int` is a `struct`, when `List<int?>` is a **case #2**, since `List<T>` is a `class`:

```
// _Int1 is List<int>
// _Int1 can be null
public List<int>? _Int1 { get; set; } 

// _Int2 is List<Nullable<int>>
// _Int2 is not supposed to be null
public List<int?> _Int2 { get; set; }

// Longer version of _Int2 type declaration
// _Int3 is List<Nullable<int>>
// _Int3 is not supposed to be null
public List<Nullable<int>> _Int3 { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there any different between 2/3 and a List that is empty ?

Comment: @EBDS: Sorry I don't follow you. `List<T>` can ever be empty (list is not `null` but has no items); but you can say it is not suppose to be `null`. Declarations `List<int?>` and `List<Nullable<int>>` are the same (short and long form of the same type: list of nullable integer items)